# Google Apps Script access values from dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I followed this tutorial https://yagisanatode.com/2018/06/10/google-apps-script-getting-input-data-from-a-dialog-box-in-google-sheets/ to create a dialog box in Google Sheets and print the values. However, I'd like to feed these values into a new function. If I try to access them in line 29, the code somewhat breaks. I say 'somewhat' because it still runs until line 28, but I think it doesn't execute line 28 as I can't see anything in the log.

I also noticed that it doesn't close the dialog box automatically once I add my two new lines. I assume it has something to do with the function closeIt in testUI.html, but I can't figure out what it is as I'm new to jQuery/Javascript.

**code.gs**

```
 //--GLOBALS--

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


function onOpen(e) {
// Create menu options
ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Admin")
        .addItem("Test", "test"))
    .addToUi();
};

function test() {
//Call the HTML file and set the width and height
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("testUI")
    .setWidth(450)
    .setHeight(300);

//Display the dialog
var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select the relevant module and unit");

};

function runsies(values) {
//Display the values submitted from the dialog box in the Logger. 
Logger.log(values);
//I added the two lines below because I'd like to access the values, not just print them.
var valuesAcc = values[0]["orange"]
Logger.log(valuesAcc);
};

//I'd like to run another function after runsies so I can work with the values which were inputted 
//into the dialogue box.
```

```js
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

function form_data(){
        var values = [{
          "orange":$("input[name=orange]:checked").val(),
          "blue":$("input[name=blue]:checked").val(),
          "green":$("input[name=green]:checked").val(),
          "purple":$("input[name=purple]:checked").val()
        }];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).runsies(values);
      };
      function closeIt(){
        google.script.host.close()
      };
```

```html
<head>
<base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      
        <table>
          <col width="60">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <tr>
            <th></th><th><strong>Unit:</strong></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><strong>Module</strong></th>
            <th><strong>n/a</strong></th>
            <th><strong>1</strong></th>
            <th><strong>2</strong></th>
            <th><strong>3</strong></th>
            <th><strong>4</strong></th>
            <th><strong>5</strong></th>
            <th><strong>6</strong></th>
            <th><strong>7</strong></th>
            <th><strong>8</strong></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Orange </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Blue </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Green </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Purple </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="8"></td> 
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
      

    </div>
```

And I think I should use a later version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing values from a Dialog is easily performed with google.script.run. Information can be found at [Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Here's a couple of examples of dialog boxes that I've done:

[Data Entry Dialog Created from Header Info on Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451551/7215091)

[Simple Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492955/7215091)